# How do I call a certain element in an array, using a user input?

Tags: java

```java
public static int gShelterSize;

public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("UTSA - Spring2022 - CS1083 - Section 004 - Project 2 - TexasShelter - written by Reid Boulet");
    System.out.print("Please, enter the number of dogs in the shelter (Max 100): ");
    gShelterSize = s.nextInt();
    mainMenu();
}

public static double[] gWeight = new double[gShelterSize];

public static void assignModifyDog(double gWeight[], int gShelterSize){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the current index(0 to "+gShelterSize+") : ");
    int index = 0;
    index = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The current weight of the dog at "+index+" is : "+gWeight[index]);
    System.out.print("Enter the weight of the new dog (0.00 - 100.00) : ");
    double currentWeight = s.nextDouble();
    if(0 < currentWeight && currentWeight <= 100){
        currentWeight = gWeight[index];
    }else{
        System.out.println("Value out of range, please, try again.");
        assignModifyDog(gWeight,gShelterSize);
    }
}
```

Whenever I compile and run the program it gives me a bunch of errors whenever it reaches `gWeight[index]` in the `println`
Errors:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at testProject2.assignModifyDog(testProject2.java:66)
    at testProject2.mainMenu(testProject2.java:30)
    at testProject2.main(testProject2.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Comment: "it gives me a bunch of errors", please add these errors to the post.

Comment: For an array of size `gShelterSize`, the range of index is from `0` to `gShelterSize - 1`, not to `gShelterSize`.

Comment: the issue is caused by the code on line 66 in the `assignModifyDog` method, I suspect it is this bit of code `gWeight[index]`, and the reason for the error is that the value `index` is greater than the number of items in the `gWeight` array. Note that arrays are 0 based, so the first item in an array is at index `[0]`, the second item is at index `[1]` etc, and if your array has 6 items, then the last item is at index `[5]`.

Comment: I think your use of `static` variables and methods is contributing to your issue here. I think the variables are not being initialised the way you expect them to be. You may want to make them instance fields instead of `static`, and initialise them in a class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the implementation of the `mainMenu()` method, so I can only guess at the contents of it. Assuming that the `gWeight` array and the `gShelterSize` variable are the static variables that you've defined, here's the problem: the `gShelterSize` is initialised to `0` until it's assigned in the `main()` method. The `gWeight` array is thus initialised to a zero-length array. Although it's defined after the `main()` method, it is initialised before the `main()` method runs. So unless it's being assigned somewhere else, it will always be a zero-length array, and `gWeight[x]` will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for any value of `x`, even `0`.

Answer (score 0):

what is 'mainMenu()' method. use num-1(when ever work with array because array always atart with 0 index) for avoid 'ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException' error